# Android google maps : Draw navigational path from point a to point b on google maps - the path should be editable

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm able to draw a path from one location to another following this article
[Drawing driving route directions between two locations using Google Directions in Google Map Android](https://www.wingsquare.com/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android/) 
but the user should be able to edit the navigational path just like google maps navigation app and also the map should support multiple paths for multiple locations.

Comment: What code have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I should be able to modify the route.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can following this. Hope it may help you out
```

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary